# Why is Environment.NewLine = "\r\n" when "\n" in a string literal functions the same?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# if you do something like `string newLine = Environment.NewLine;` and inspect the value of `newLine` you'll find that it is `"\r\n"`. However, if I do something like;

```
  string[] test = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

  Console.WriteLine("With plain slash n:");
  Console.Write(String.Join("\n", test));
  Console.WriteLine("\nWith Environment.NewLine:");
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, test));
```

The output is functionally the same.

Why is `Environment.NewLine` set to `\r\n` instead of just `\n`? Doesn't that just make it more difficult to convert from string to character array? Also I read something which led me to believe some input fields don't count `Environment.NewLine` as two characters which could cause problems if your backing fields are restricted to the length of the input field. Are there any positive reasons for it? Is it just legacy cruft at this point?

Comment: I would say, just for historical reasons. And this is not the most weird thing.

Comment: It's somewhat legacy.  Some OSs (unix/linux are some) use just \n to move to the start of a new line.  Microsoft OSs used \n to move to a new line and \r to return to the start of that line.

Comment: The console's output stream is open in text mode, so `\n` characters are automatically translated into `\r\n` on Windows platforms. `Environment.NewLine` would be necessary to output Windows CR/LF pairs into binary streams.

Comment: .NET is an abstraction over the platform it is running on. So, whether you run your .NET app in Windows or Linux, '\n' automatically translates internally to whatever the underlying platform thinks newline should be. Use of 'Environment' class is to explicitly request CLI runtime to return what the actual newline for the platform is. For all other instances, you use '\n'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The point of Environment.NewLine is to return the newline character for the platform. Presumably for implementations of the .NET framework atop Linux or Unix, it would return just \n.

Comment: Good point. I was ignoring the `Environment` portion of it because for me (please no one rage about Mono) C#/.NET is a Windows language. So the question should actually be asking why Windows uses \r\n rather than why `Environment.NewLine` uses it.

Comment: +1, but I technically *newline character*, should be *character sequence representing a newline* (or similar), since it's usually not a single character.

Answer (score 10):

"New line" in windows/dos is, by convention, CR+LF (`"\r\n"`, "\x0D\x0A"). In the *nix world, "new line" is, by convention, a single LF character ("\n","\0A"). In the pre-OS X Macintosh world, "new line" is, again by convention, a single LF character ("\r","\x0D"). Toss IBM mainframes into the mix and its worse: EBCDIC control character set comprises CR, LF *and* a specific **NL** control character.

The reason for this is historical and has to do with the fact that ASCII doesn't have an actual NL (new line) control character: it just has CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed). The various OSes were developed with different printing terminals, and their interpretation of the meaning of these control characters, on which the various operating systems were developed and you have your newline schism.

The CLR I/O system tries to follow Postel's Law ("Be generous in what you accept and strict in what you emit") and so is agnostic on input WRT new line conventions. Consequently, the standard CLR `TextReader` implementations accept any of CR+LF, CR or LF as constituting a new line indicator. However, on output, `WriteLine()`, by default, appends the value of `Environment.NewLine'.

Answer (score 0):

DOS and Windows use the combination of carriage return (\u000D) + Line Feed  (new line \n \u000A) to represent a single new line. Different platoforms have different settings (see: [Wiki-NewLine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). So C# is following the standard for Windows and DOS as expected when an application is run in Windows.